# How is a bitmap's memory managed on Android?

Tags: java, android, memory, bitmap, garbage-collection

I am following [this article](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html) on Android developer, which quotes :

> On Android 2.3.3 (API level 10) and lower, the backing pixel data for
>   a bitmap is stored in native memory. It is separate from the bitmap
>   itself, which is stored in the Dalvik heap. The pixel data in native
>   memory is not released in a predictable manner, potentially causing an
>   application to briefly exceed its memory limits and crash. As of
>   Android 3.0 (API level 11), the pixel data is stored on the Dalvik
>   heap along with the associated bitmap.

There is [another article](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2367) which confused me further :

> A Bitmap is a thin wrapper around a native heap memory area that
>   stores pixel data.

I have multiple doubts :

1. What is the difference between Dalvik heap, native heap and native memory ?
2. How is a bitmap different from the pixel data ? My understanding is that any image file (unless it's a vector image) is called bitmap - which is compressed. Android decompresses/decodes this information to render pixels on screen. If I am correct, why do we need the compressed bitmap anymore ?
3. How does a class like [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) work ? My understanding is that the entire bitmap is decoded/decompressed first, and then areas out of bound are ignored - this will help in memory efficiency but will not make decoding faster. Am I correct ?
4. What exactly happens when a bitmap is recycled ?

Answer (score -3):

When having an OutOfMemoryError, try the code below.

```
try {
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), m, true);
    return bitmap;
} catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), m, true);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: This is not answering any of my questions.